# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell how to set the selection to pass data from the current view to another one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller with a tableview inside it , in the table view i implemented a collection view with horizontal scrolling, the data appears correctly but i want to go to another view controller when i click on the collection view cell passing a string to that view , how can i handle this process .
thanks in advance

Comment: You can pass data with Pushing view controller, Protocol Delegate, Notification and many more.

Comment: Please refer this stack answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309122/3278326

Comment: the problem is when i click the collection view cell it click it only and doesn't affect the table cell , i used instance to set the value of a string in the other view to test before doing it with delegate methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choice

1) Implement Collection view delegate & datasource inside view controller. You can do this in tableview's cellForRowAt method like `cell.collectionview.datasource = self`

2) You can create delegate / closure  to pass data from Collection View -> TableView Cell --> UIViewController

Hope it is helpful And let me know if you need example

**EXAMPLE**

As you have finding difficulties to understand theoretically here is example

suppose in your view controller

You have tableview datasource like below

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"identifer", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

     // You have collection view inside tableview cell so 

       cell.yourCollectionViewObject.dataSource = self 
       cell.yourCollectionViewObject.delegate = self 

        return cell
    }
```

Implement or Move  the datasource & Delegate in Your view Controller and push or present view controller you want to

Comment: i implemented the collection view cell with it's data , then implemented table cell with protocols and dequeue the collection cell inside it, then in the controller i implement the table protocols , that's why the view of cell is correct but the click is separated like when i click on the collection cell it only click this cell not the table cell too

Comment: @TamerEzzat You want to identify which tableview cell clicked when Collectionview cell tapped ?

Comment: i want the controller to present another one when i click on the collectionview cell but it's defined in the swift file of tableview cell so it can't call self.present function

Comment: @TamerEzzat You have to create delegate then.  Create delegate (protocol) and pass events to UIViewController , In your case delegate will be Colectioinview cell  to -> tableview cell -> UIView Controller

Comment: @TamerEzzat Another option is don't set datasource & Delegate to tableview cell's swift file. You can do this in view controller it self (see Option 1 in answer)

Comment: else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let departmentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DepartmentCell", for: indexPath) as! DepartmentsCellView
            departmentCell.departmentsLbl.text = "Departments"
            departmentCell.scrollableView.dataSource = self
            return departmentCell
        }


the function inside the view controller , if i add collectionview delegate and datasource it must add it's functions ,the line of cell.scrollableView.datasource = self is an error "Cannot assign value of type 'HomeVC' to type 'UICollectionViewDataSource?'"

Comment: @TamerEzzat  Now you have to replace  `class HomeVC:UIViewController`  to `class HomeVC:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate`

Comment: @TamerEzzat You need to see tutorials before implementing any thing

Comment: @TamerEzzat Please accept my answer as accepted (click on right button ) So it might helpful to other searching for same. And UP VOTE if you want to :)